# Combobox in automatically closing popup

Tags: forms, react-native, popup

I'm new to React Native and want help with form making. I need a combobox, where a user should choose an option from several. When user clicks the combobox component, I want options in something like a popup on screen without going to another page, and once the option is chosen the popup or whatever automatically closes.

I created a standard combobox to select the option, but I want to show options in a popup with closure when the option has been chosen.

Is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Picker](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html) component.

Also check [this library](https://github.com/beefe/react-native-picker) - it wrap native pickers. I believe you will get a popup picker in Android and a bottom-modal picker in iOS (just like native)

Comment: thank you. Actually I used Picker but what is wanted from me in app is that, the choices in picker should be popped-up. Is it possible to make alert when the component clicked and then in the alert user pick the option?

Comment: Try the library I mentioned. It will give you the native behaviour. In Android you can achieve what you said. For iOS its a modal in the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, almost 2 years since you asked this question. But, maybe there are others who come up to this thread & wants to know the other option to display combobox like popup. This [react-native-material-dropdown](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown) might be great for you. Try it !

[image]